# Joining subcluster based on distance

Tags: cluster-analysis

I have the following sequence data:

```
data = {"TTGTTCTTGATA", "TACTTGAACGTT", "TTTGGAGAATAT", "GGGGTGTGAAAA", 
"TGCGGTTGAGTG", "TAGACTCGCTAC", "ATTGTAAAGACA", "TTCACGGTGGTT", 
"TATCTTCGTTTG", "TATACTGGTTTG"}
```

I did hierarchical clustering on them using `HammingDistance`. And the dendrogram plot is something like this:

[image]

The code I used is:

```
Needs["HierarchicalClustering`"];
DendrogramPlot[data, Axes -> {False, True}, 
 DistanceFunction -> HammingDistance, Linkage -> "Single"]
```

What I want to do is joining the subclusters that are below a certain distance. For example, I'd like to join the subclusters that are within distance 4 and to report the final number of clusters after joining subclusters.

The `Findcluster` in Mathematica lets one choose the number of clusters, not the cutoff distance. Any idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your last edit was a major improvement. However, the only thing that I can contribute at the moment is that you can obtain essentially the same functionality with `G = ClusteringTree[data, DistanceFunction -> HammingDistance, 
   ClusterDissimilarityFunction -> "Single"];
Dendrogram[G]`. The advantage is that `G` is now a `Graph` object, which can be analyzed further (in contrast to `Dendrogram` and `DendrogramPlot`, which are `Graphics` objects).